# Play with Scala: how to nest special characters

Tags: scala, playframework

I am working with Play and Scala and can't seem to figure out this one.
In my controller, I have 2 maps with the same key but different values. Then, on the view, I iterate over the first map and try to use the key (coming from the iterator) to do a lookup on the second one. When I do this

```
@map1.map { f =>
    <span>Key: @f._1</span>
    <span>Value from second map: @map2.getOrElse(@f._1, "default value")
}
```

It doesn't compile. It complains with the following error message: "illegal start of simple expression" (pointing to the second @f._1).
It seems clear that the nested @ is what is causing the problem because if I replace the second @f._1 by a constant, it works fine.

```
@map1.map { f =>
    <span>Key: @f._1</span>
    <span>Value from second map: @map2.getOrElse("my known key", "default value")
}
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to nest these 2 @? I tried various things (double @, double quotes) but that didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it without using "@" like this:

```
@map1.map { f =>
<span>Key: @f._1</span>
<span>Value from second map: @map2.getOrElse(f._1, "default value")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `if` in Play are not simple Scala. It's a special templating construction. Inside `{}` you may use any html-code including nested @-expressions.

On the contrary — @-expressions are mostly Scala (excluding `map`s and `if`s, `flatMap`s, and other `for`-comprehensions).

Have a look at Play's templating engine (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplates).

In your case `@map2.getOrElse(f._1, "default value")` is a simple Scala expression without `if`s and `map`s. So @ is not needed here.